# como crear un catalogo de metodos dinamico en Python

Tags: python, poo

Quiero crear un cliente para consumir un web service, entonces lo que he decidido es crear una clase llamada Methods y en el constructor instancio el cliente de zeep

```
from zeep import Client
class Methods:
def __init__(self) -> None:
    self.client = Client()
```

Hasta aqui todo correcto, pero luego me han pasado una serie de metodos que tiene el web service

```
stmethodLoginTAE = "st_Login_User"
stmethodAddClient = "st_add_clients_pos"
stmethodTransaction = "st_Request_Transaction"
stmethodCheck = "st_check_transaction"
```

lo de menos seria crear una funcion por metodo, pero siento que seria demasiado repetitivo el codigo

```
class Methods:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
       self.client = Client()

def __call(self, method, params, options: Options):
    result = self.client.service[method](params)
    return result

@classmethod
def login_tae(self, params: Any = None):
    lt = self.__call(
        self,
        "st_Login_User",
        params,
    )

    return lt

@classmethod
def add_client(self, params: Any = None):
    lt = self.__call(
        self,
        "st_add_clients_pos",
        params,
    )

    return lt

@classmethod
def products(self, params: Any = None):
    lt = self.__call(
        self,
        "st_pos_prices_products",
        params,
    )

    return lt
```

cree un metodo privado para poder llamar el servicio, pero aun creo que es muy arcaico, hubiera alguna forma de solo mandar el metodo como un parametro, pero que quedara una sintaxis algo asi

```
ws_tae.add_client(params=params)
```

sin necesidad de crear metodo por metodo dentro de la clase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una pregunta muy interesante!

Puedes usar el método magico [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) para controlar que devolverá la clase cuando se intenta acceder a un atributo.

Cuando llamas a un método de clase, Python internamente primero obtiene el método usando `__getattribute__` y luego lo llama.

El plan sería que cuando se intente acceder a un atributo, retorne el método original proveniente de `Client.service` y llamar directamente a eso.

#### Código de ejemplo

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.service = {"add_client":print}

class Methods:
    def __init__(self):
       self.client = Client()

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return super().__getattribute__("client").service[name]


metodos = Methods()
metodos.add_client("hola", "mundo")
```

En este código, el atributo service de cliente es un diccionario cuyo key es add_client y el valor es la función print.

Esta linea:

```
super().__getattribute__(...)
```

Es equivalente a

```
[la clase padre].__getattribute__(self, ...)
```

Nos permite acceder a los atributos de la forma convencional.

#### Produce

```
hola mundo
```

Comment: muchas gracias!, realmente me funciono perfecto, al final solo tuve que buscar como agregar un parametro "estatico" y listo ahora me quedo como lo queria, muchas gracias!